# Extract URL slug using PHP. Building a URL shortener

Tags: php, apache, http, url, nginx

I'm building a URL shortening web app using PHP. I am able to generate shorter URLs successfully. But I'm not able to redirect the users when they visit the shortened URL.

If the user enters `https://example.com/aBc1X`, I'd like to capture the `aBc1X`. I'll then query the database to find the original URL and then redirect.

My question is, **how can I extract the `aBc1X` from the above URL?**

P.S. I'll use either Apache or Nginx.

Comment: I'd recommend [YOURLS](https://github.com/YOURLS/YOURLS). Save you some time.

Comment: @wogsland I'm building this as a project in college.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to do for you.
First you have to redirect all traffic to one file which will be your router file. You can do this by placing a few rules in .htaccess file. I will put there some generic rules to start with (this one come from Wordpress):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^redirect\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /redirect.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

They tell that everywhere url points to which isn't file or directory will run file redirect.php. You may want to tweak that settings to your needs.

Then in redirect.php you can capture url by looking inside `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.
For url `http://example.com/any-url-i-want` you would have
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/any-url-i-want`.

Now the only thing you need is to find the url in database, and do a redirect.
I guess you can handle string operations at this point, either by using parse_url, regular expressions, or simple string cutting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to do this on Ngnix?

Comment: I don't have much experience with nginx. But I think that you should be able to convert or write equivalent rules for nginx. This short article should help http://nginxlibrary.com/wordpress-permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

You want to use;

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

That will return what you're looking for.

You can see the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: I think OP means the user is entering the URL as an input to a form, not the page the user is on.

Comment: That's not the way I read it - _"I am able to generate shorter URLs successfully. But I'm not able to redirect the users when they visit the shortened URL."_

Comment: My answer does presume the OP has got every generated URL being handled by one PHP script however.

Comment: I see what you mean. Could read that way as well. I guess we'll find out when we see which answer he picks.

Answer (score 0):

To parse the url

```
$url = "https://example.com/aBc1X";
$path = ltrim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
```

Then `$path` will be `aBc1X` as desired. Note that any query following a `?` will be omitted in this solution. For more details have a look at the [documentation of the `parse_url` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: $path will actually include the "/" at the beginning, so that may need to be trimmed off.

Comment: @BA_Webimax Thanks - fixed!